# pulling info from a log file and sending a notification email using python

Tags: python, ssh, freebsd

I am working on a project for work that requires me to pull information from a logfile and send a notification anytime it finds a the specific information. For example the exact issue I am working on is I am needing to create a python script that will look into may /var/log/auth.log (FreeBSD system) and pull any invalid SSH login attempts, then proceed to email me and another co-worker anytime there is an offense.

I've been looking all over for a few days now and have had minimal success any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're really after is a daemon like `fail2ban`, which is specifically designed to examine log files for intrusion attempts.

From the [`fail2ban` wiki:](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)

> Fail2ban scans log files (e.g. /var/log/apache/error_log) and bans IPs
>   that show the malicious signs -- too many password failures, seeking
>   for exploits, etc. Generally Fail2Ban then used to update firewall
>   rules to reject the IP addresses for a specified amount of time,
>   although any arbitrary other action (e.g. **sending an email**, or
>   ejecting CD-ROM tray) could also be configured. Out of the box
>   Fail2Ban comes with filters for various services (apache, curier, **ssh**,
>   etc).

This would probably work better than any solution you baked yourself.

---

That said, if you did want to roll your own, the naive way to implement periodic checking of a file is simply to read it every five minutes and see if it's changed.

The smarter way is to use the operating system's file monitoring service, which hooks into the filesystem driver and notifies you as soon as the file changes. This has the dual benefits that your code will take less CPU time, and it will respond immediately whenever the file changes.

On Linux the service is called `inotify`. BSD and Windows have an equivalent feature.

Comment: Note: I gave what I think is a solution that will solve your actual problem (SSH logfile monitoring) but Gabi's and Ethan's answers will help you if you really do want to roll your own custom solution in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You could run a `cron` job every few minutes that checks for changes in that file. If there are any changes, it will email you, by using, for example, `smtplib`. Here is an example of smtplib usage with sendgrid: http://docs.sendgrid.com/documentation/get-started/integrate/examples/python-email-example-using-smtp/

How do you find out if a file was modified?

1. You keep a copy of the file as it looked in the previous script run, and compare that to the current contents
2. You check the file's [last modification time](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime).

This is just a general idea that can be tweaked, and all the 'ingredients' can be found on google, so you should be able to implement it by googling yourself.

Hope this helps.

Comment: As in my answer, the operating system's file monitoring service is probably a better way to check if a file has changed. Instead of repeatedly polling the file to see if its `mtime` has changed, just ask the operating system to notify you when the file has been written to. (On Linux, use `inotify`.)

Comment: On FreeBSD, you can use kqueue(2) via the devel/py-kqueue port.

Answer (score 0):

As a rough idea for a cron job:

```
with open('/var/log/auth.log') as auth:
    for line in auth:
        if 'blahblah' in line:
            # send email
```

You'll want to check out the [email module](http://docs.python.org/library/email) for emailing details.  You'll also want a way to keep track of what's already been scanned, so you don't end up sending duplicate emails.